# JSP Redirection and passing value

Tags: java, jsp, struts

I have a JSP in which i am redirecting to another jsp like
  ,i dont have any other data in that jsp,i want to pass a value from this jsp(index.jsp) to the redirected jsp(login.jsp),how will i do this?

Here "logonInput" is defined in struts-config.xml

index.JSP is like

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html;charset=UTF-8"%>
<%@ taglib uri="http://struts.apache.org/tags-logic" prefix="logic" %>
<%
String sessionExpired=(String)request.getAttribute("SessionExpired");
%>

<logic:redirect forward="logonInput"/>
```

I want to display or pass the value sessionExpired to login.jsp

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**To forward a parameter using a session:**

In your first jsp page.

```
session.setAttribute("sessionExpired", sessionExpired);
```

*To read:*

```
session.getAttribute("sessionExpired");
```

**To forward a parameter using in the request:**

```
request.setAttribute("sessionExpired", sessionExpired);
```

**Forward parameter using jsp forward tag:**

```
<jsp: forward page="login.jsp">
  <jsp: param name="sessionExpired" value='<%request.getParameter("sessionExpired")%>'/> 
</jsp: forward>
```

**Forward parameter using logic:redirect:** 
**Edit**
Add the parameter to the request.

```
<%request.setAttribute("sessionExpired",sessionExpired);%>
```

This will pass the parameter set in the initial request parameter to the forwarded page.

```
<logic:redirect forward=login.jsp" paramId="sessionExpired" paramName="sessionExpired" />
```

*To read:*

```
String sessionExpired=(String)request.getAttribute("sessionExpired");
```

Comment: This is fine,is there a way to pass the value along with <logic:redirect forward="logonInput"/>

Comment: Ya session approach do works fine,i am aware of it,i wanted something passed along with <logic:redirect forward="logonInput"/>

Comment: <logic:redirect forward=login.jsp" paramId="sessionExpired" paramName="<%= sessionExpired%>" /> in index.jsp 
and login.jsp wil have String sessionExpired=(String)request.getAttribute("sessionExpired");

is not working,wil get an error saying no scope is defined

Comment: <logic:redirect forward=login.jsp" paramId="sessionExpired" paramName="sessionExpired" />

This line should just forward the original parameter. The other line will add a parameter of the name of the value of sessionExpired.

Comment: Cannot find bean: "sessionExpired" in any scope is the error after using <logic:redirect forward=login.jsp" paramId="sessionExpired" paramName="sessionExpired" />

Comment: Make sure redirect="true" isn't set in your action mapping this will create a new request when the page is forwarded.

Comment: did not worked out even after removing rediect=true,anyways i am goingto use session approach,thanks a lot

Comment: It's probably something small. I will update my answer if I find it.