# Redirect a JSP request to itself after executing in a Servlet

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, request

I am trying to return a JSP request back to the calling Page with the help of a Java servlet class.
This means that after adding a comment on a JSP page, the comment reappears on the JSP page as well after sending the request object to the servlet.
This is the calling JSP code:

```
 <form action="/WebAppOpe/UploadComments" method="post">
                        <textarea name="comment" placeholder="Comment" column="10"></textarea>
                        <input type="submit" value="Post Comment" class="btn-login" name="btn_post" />
                        <input type ="hidden" name="carIdComment" value="${car.carId}" />
 </form>
```

And this is the servlet code of the UploadComments URI for sending the request back to the source.

```
        RequestDispatcher rd = request.getRequestDispatcher("model.jsp?" + request.getParameter("carIdComment"));
        rd.forward(request, response);
        response.sendRedirect("model.jsp?"+  request.getParameter("carIdComment"));
```

Comment: `RequestDispatcher` will send your request to `/WebAppOpe/model.jsp?<some_value>`
Is that your calling jsp??

Comment: Yes, that is my calling jsp

Comment: Have you tried only with response.sendRedirect("...");. I mean, without RequestDispatcher lines? Maybe add it (response.sendRedirect("...")) to a finally block.

Comment: no I have not done so, the solution by lucumt worked fine. Thanks for your comment tiago.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you just want to refresh the current page,`ajax` is a better choice for you.

For you current design,both `forward` and `redirect` are okay,but something need to pay attention:

1. if you use `redirect`,you can set parameters via the url
2. after `forward` or `redirect`,you need to query the exits comments,which means that you had can either `redirect` to a new url and query data, or query the data before `forward`.

Comment: Thanks>
I tried redirect and it works but the problem is how I can carry my data and parameters back to the jsp page from itself to the servlet and back to itself. 
I will try to implement ajax.

Comment: @DavidEnoma for carry data,you can check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3226970/jsp-redirection-and-passing-value