# Redirect the HTML page to another one using servlet

Tags: java, html, servlet-3.0

I used this method and the commented once but it did not work , the print method work properly but the redirection didn't.

```
        else if (action.contentEquals("Login")) 
    {

        RequestDispatcher view = request.getRequestDispatcher("mainPage.html");
        try {
            System.out.print("Login now");
            view.forward(request, response);
        } catch (ServletException e1) {
            System.out.print("Error Loging in");
        } 


        /*try {
            System.out.print("Login now");
             response.sendRedirect("mainPage.html");
             return;

        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.print("Error");      }
        */
    }
```

Comment: if you are using servlets, why aren't you using jsp or jsf instead of html?

Comment: have you tried logging after `view.forward(...)` See if the control reaches there. If it does then definitely something is wrong. if Possible give the whole controller code Maybe error lies there

Answer (score 0):

You can get some ideas here:

[Redirecting a calling JSP to itself using RequestDispatcher object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50714411/redirecting-a-calling-jsp-to-itself-using-requestdispatcher-object)

```
RequestDispatcher view = request.getRequestDispatcher("mainPage.html");
    try {
        System.out.print("Login now");
        view.forward(request, response);
        response.sendRedirect("mainPage.html");
    } catch (ServletException e1) {
        System.out.print("Error Loging in");
    }
```

Comment: what should I do in my case , please help